# Как вывести какой-то текст в какую-то точку экрана?

Tags: python, графика, pygame

Я с помощью модуля `pygame` сделал окно 500x500 пикселей.

Как вывести какой-то текст в какую-то точку экрана?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

sc = pygame.display.set_mode((300,200))
sc.fill((255, 255, 255))

f1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
text1 = f1.render('Hello Привет', 1, (180, 0, 0))


sc.blit(text1, (10, 50))


pygame.display.update()

while 1:
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

Стянул пример [отсюда](https://younglinux.info/pygame/font)

Comment: pygame.display.update()
должен быть внутри основного цикла